# Unable to pair Magic Mouse and keyboard - only Unknown and "not set up"

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04, magic-mouse

I try to setup / pair a magic mouse and keyboard with a new Bluetooth stick on my Desktop Ubuntu 20.04.

Unfortunately I do only see Unknown devices and am unable to connect them :/

How to debug / fix this?

[image]

Comment: this thread may help: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-963641.html

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by removing the batteries from the wireless keyboard and from the magic mouse for 10+ seconds.

After that the devices are detected and paired successfully